# How to send a class (not object) in a parameter in C++?

Tags: c++, delphi

I want to send a class (not an object) as a parameter. In Delphi, I can use this:

```
TDemo = class of baseclass;
```

In C++, how can I write this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ has no equivalent to Delphi metaclass types, so what you are asking for is simply not possible.